# Ansible specifying inventory file doesn't work

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to specify inventory file in Ansible.

The help command output:

```
  -i INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                        specify inventory host file
                        (default=/usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts)
```

I tried to do like this:

```
 ansible -i /Users/liu/personal/test_ansible/hosts
```

but it doesn't work and instead it outputs the help content once again:

```
➜  test_ansible  ansible -i /Users/liu/personal/test_ansible/hosts
Usage: ansible <host-pattern> [options]

Options:
  -a MODULE_ARGS, --args=MODULE_ARGS
                        module arguments
  --ask-become-pass     ask for privilege escalation password
  -k, --ask-pass        ask for SSH password
  --ask-su-pass         ask for su password (deprecated, use become)
  -K, --ask-sudo-pass   ask for sudo password (deprecated, use become)
  --ask-vault-pass      ask for vault password
  -B SECONDS, --background=SECONDS
                        run asynchronously, failing after X seconds
                        (default=N/A)
  .......
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=/Users/liu/personal/test_ansible/hosts
```

then will be ok!

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `ansible` command it will run ad-hoc Ansible modules rather than the more typical Ansible playbooks (which is ran by the `ansible-playbook` executable instead).

The `ansible` executable has a requirement of a "host pattern" which will match a group of remote nodes defined in the inventory.

So if we supplied an inventory file (named `inventory.ini` for this example) that looked like this:

```
[web]
web-1.example.org
web-2.example.org

[app]
app-1.example.org
app-2.example.org
app-3.example.org

[database:children]
database-master
database-slave

[database-master]
database-master.example.org

[database-child]
database-slave1.example.org
database-slave2.example.org
```

We could target just the web nodes by using `ansible web -i /path/to/inventory.ini -m ping` to get Ansible to use the ping module against the web-1.example.org and web-2.example.org.

Alternatively we could target all of the database nodes including the master and the 2 slaves by using `ansible database -i /path/to/inventory.ini -m ping`.

And finally, we can also target all of the servers in the inventory by using the "magic" `all` group that covers all of the groups in the inventory file by using `ansible all -i /path/to/inventory.ini -m ping`.